# Can you split the max[] function?

Tags: geometry

I need to prove that $(A\times A',d_2)$ a metric space is, where $d_2=((a_0,a_0'),(a_1,a_1'))=\max\{d(a_0,a_1),d'(a_0',a_1')\}.$ Also defined are the metric spaces $(A,d)$ and $(A',d')$.

I have proven the first two properties of a metric space, but I get stuck on the triangle equality.

Is it mathematically correct to say the following?

\begin{align*}
\max\{d(a_0,a_1),d'(a_0',a_1')\}&\leq \max\{d(a_0,a_2)+d(a_2,a_1),d'(a_0',a_2')+d(a_2',a_1')\} \\
&= \max\{d(a_0,a_2),d'(a_0',a_2')\}+\max\{d(a_2,a_1),d'(a_2',a_1')\}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

This statement is in general wrong.

Let's consider that $d(a_0, a_2) = 5, d(a_2, a_1) = 3, d'(a_0', a_2') = 1, d'(a_2', a_1') = 3$. Then you get $$\max\{d(a_0, a_2) + d(a_2, a_1), d'(a_0',a_2') + d'(a_2', a_1')\} = \max\{5+3, 1+4\} = \max\{8, 5\} = 8, $$ but on the other side $$ \max\{d(a_0, a_2), d'(a_0',a_2')\} + \max\{ d(a_2, a_1),d'(a_2', a_1')  \} = \max\{5,1\} + \max\{3,4\} = 5 +4 = 9.$$

But, it is possible to show that $$ \max\{a+c, b+d\} \leq \max\{a,b\} + \max\{c,d\}. $$

With this inequality you also still showed the triangle inequality.

Comment: Yes, i had a typo there. I corrected it now.